# How to run a specific test method in firebase test labs using ./gradlew :app:assembleAndroidTest

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I am generating apk for running my UI test cases in firebase test labs using 
./gradlew :app:assembleDebug and ./gradlew :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest

I am uploading my app apk and my test apk in firebase test labs  where it is running all my Testclasses , But I want to run only a particular test class

I also tried with ./gradlew :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.myapp.uitest.tests.LoginTest

but no luck on that , it still ran all the test class

Am I missing anything , can any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way doing this is with [gcloud --test-targets](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-targets).

E.g. to only run tests in specific sub-packages:

```sh
gcloud firebase test android run \
  --app path/to/app.apk \
  --test path/to/tests.apk \
  --device model=walleye,version=26  \
  --test-targets "package com.my.package.tests1","package com.my.package.tests2"
```

There are other target identifiers for classes, annotations, ...

Comment: is there a way to add test-targets in my Gradle file ?

Comment: No. The "-P" option is a "runtime" thing. It is not encoded in the APK itself, but gradle sends the information to the Android instrumentation on the device to only run these tests.